# Twitter Web Intent returns "Sorry, that page doesn't exist!" error for a site that exists

Tags: twitter, urlencode

Just trying to add a basic twitter share button to my site. I want to let users tweet a link to a SoundCloud page. I followed [this tutorial](https://jonsuh.com/blog/social-share-links/) for building simple social media buttons. Twitter returns a "Sorry, that page doesn't exist!" error.

Website to share: `https://soundcloud.com/thegrindwithkevin/011-postmortem-team-eve-61816`
Website url encoded: `https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fthegrindwithkevin%2F011-postmortem-team-eve-61816`

Code for HTML link:

```
<a className="custom-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/
           ?text=Check%20out%20this%20podcast!
           &url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fthegrindwithkevin%2F011-postmortem-team-eve-61816
           &via=thegrindwithkev"
         target="_blank">Share on Twitter</a>
```

Apologies in advance for the super basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is as embarrassing as the question: Twitter did not like the (hidden) line breaks in the URL string. Alls well now.